# Setting Env variables to run Python and Anaconda in OSX

Tags: python, macos, system, anaconda, darwin

I'm trying to learn Anaconda while not ruining my Python development and projects.

I remember (several machines ago) I was able to create(?) an environment variable in my PATH so I could run the OS X Python install by invoking '**python**' and Python 3.x by invoking '**python3**', however I can't recall how this was done, and not having luck finding it.  I'd like to use this approach, rather than all the virtualenv solutions I've been finding.

The result I'd like would be to have something like that except maybe **apython** for the anaconda and **python** for the OS X/Darwin veresion.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: homebrew & virtualenv are your friend.

Comment: PATH *is* an environment variable, it contains the names of directories to search.